# Why is so much work spent on String Theory (despite lack of evidence), contrary to the Rishon Model?

Tags: string-theory

I read [this](https://thewire.in/science/theres-no-conflict-lack-evidence-string-theory-work-done) interview with Nathan Seiberg, one of the most outspoken physicists of String Theory. In this interview he writes:

> There are two correct statements. One is that at the moment there is no experimental evidence. We don’t know when the verification will come or where it will come from. Maybe someone smart will figure it out next year, maybe it will take three years, maybe 300. We don’t know. The other thing is that there is some effort going into it. You can ask whether it is justified. And I can justify it on several fronts.

It's clear we conclude from this quote that he has already made up his mind: the theory is right. He tells us that it's just a matter of time (1year, 300 years) before the theory is confirmed. Having said that, that must be the attitude of everyone who favors a particular theory.

He mentions as the most important justification:

> Whenever you work on something and try to solve one problem, and you end up helping or solving many other problems, it is a sign that what you are doing is good.

Of course, helping or solving other problems (by inventing new math, for example) is a good thing. But this doesn't mean you're on the right track in pursuing String Theory. There is a plethora of theories trying to unify GR and QFT and maybe GR and QFT can't be unified at all.

Likewise, there is, at the moment, no experimental evidence for the [Rishon model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model) (here I am again with one of my favorite theories), which gives a deepened understanding though of the reaction between elementary particles and gives an explanation for the asymmetry of matter-antimatter: it simply doesn't exist in this model. The mass problem is easily resolved (the Higgs field doesn't exist in this model). So the (in 2012) discovered particle that was thought to be the Higgs is just another particle. The prediction of this particle field could be a part of the Rishon Model too, which doesn't see the weak force (from which the Higgs field ultimately derives) as fundamental but as a residue force of a more fundamental force called the [hypercolor force](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222457879_A_schematic_model_of_quarks_and_leptons).

Why isn't more effort invested in this theory, despite the lack of evidence? Nathan Seiberg tells us that evidence for the String Theory will one day be found, and one can say the same for the Rishon Model. But maybe someone smart will figure it out next year, maybe it will take three years, maybe 300. We don’t know. When we can reach high enough energies in particle colliders, the substructure of all massive "elementary" particles will surely be revealed.

Is the only difference that String theory has become mainstream and the Rishon Theory not?

Note that I have stated just facts and no opinions. If so, who can tell me what is the opinion-based part?

Like @G.Smith said rightly, Seiberg himself worked on RT too. See for example [this](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/particle/harari/files/Nuclear_PhysicsB_Vol204.pdf) article, written by Harari and his former student Seiberg. But I guess he didn't pursue the theory further because around the time the article was written, string theory was a promising approach with which a young student (i.e. Seiberg) could better be involved, to have more certainty for a promising career. To be honest, I didn't know that this article exists and both of them worked together on RT. So it's a coïncidense that I picked Seiberg in my question.

Comment: You seem to be getting something from that first quote that the words don't actually imply.  "_There are two correct statements. One is that at the moment there is no experimental evidence.... The other thing is that there is some effort going into it. You can ask whether it is justified. And I can justify it on several fronts._" I see no way to conclude from that quote that he decided string theory was correct; just that it was worth investigating further (which it sounds like he is supporting due to the possibility of discovering _something_ useful while doing string theory tests).

Comment: You could read abot Stephen Hawking...

Comment: @Jmac-He writes: Maybe someone smart will figure it out next year, maybe it will take three years, maybe 300. We don’t know.  This is why I think that he thinks string theory is correct.

Comment: @Solar Mike- What does he have to to with this?

Comment: @descheleschilder FYI putting the - right after my name means it doesn't notify me of the comment.  What he says is "_We don’t know when the verification will come or where it will come from. Maybe someone smart will figure it out next year, maybe it will take three years, maybe 300. We don’t know._"  None of that to me suggests that he thinks string theory must be correct; just that the breakthrough could come at any time if it is.  None of his statements there imply he knows or believes anything strongly about string theory; just that it has the potential to give results in some timeframe.

Comment: But he implies the verification __will__ come, meaning he is convinced of the theory's correspondence to reality. But doesn't everyone who is supporting a certain theory is doing this? It would be strange if you don't (though ib QFT the situation is somewhat problematic). I'm sure that the RT is the truth about elementary particles.

Comment: @descheleschilder To me that wording doesn't say that he's confident it will come.  If you're not sure if something is going to happen at all, those statements still seem fine to me.

Comment: Regarding your fondness for rishons... Don’t you find it instructive that the same Nathan Seiberg was a major developer of rishon theory but no longer is?

Comment: Very instructive! This only goes to show that he was more interested in string theory because there was more money to earn in following the path of strings. Rishon theory never made it to the mainstream, so...It was Haim Harari though who invented the RT, so Seiberg wasn't a major developer.

Comment: Your first statement about Seiberg is slanderous and unsubstantiated, and your second is false.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a question. And I am really not a string theory specialist. What I can say is that physics is made by humans. Trends, fashion, politics about who has PhD credits or becoming a team leader, exist. Pride to be cited in popular science journals exist. Some theory bearers are more hated for their personality than for their alternative theory, I think. During the 80s, string theory was THE theory in popular science talks - and the only one getting a significant amount of credits. After 40 years without a real breakthrough (whatever impressive progresses the theory has made), people felt the need to see something else, and then one other theory - Quantum Loop Theory - could make its way to credit lines and media coverage. This is mainly human. You don't like to throw away decades of work, even if you're a scientist (who are not immune to escalation of commitment in any way). You always prefer to understand new things from what you already know than to invest energy and time in learning a totally different way - even if you're a scientist. You often prefer to be seen as being on the winning side - even if you're a scientist.

This human behaviour, I think, is universal and doesn't say a lot about validity of M-Theory, QLT, or any other outsider. Maybe there is a human component too to why you love the Rishon Model so much?

Comment: Of course, there is a human component! The theory says there are only 2(!) elementary particles (how economic can it get?). It can explain every reaction between elementary particles (which in this theory are not really elementary), it's easy to explain the decay of the proton, it explains that the asymmetry of matter-antimatter problem doesn't exist. It easily explains the generations of quarks and leptons. Take your pick. How can one with a sane mind ignore these features? I can't see any feature of ST which by which I'm allured.

Comment: Why don't throw a theory that doesn't work? Only because so many efforts have been put in it? One can carry on and on, but the theory is far away from direct experimental proof. Maybe indirect proof will do, but nonetheless. I think one can better put the (mainly public)  money in developing a theory that will bear the fruits of experimental proof at much lower energies.

Comment: You are confusing a vast financial and political corruption in modern science for a "human component".

Comment: A young physicist can embrace with fire one of the 1000 alternative theory trying to go further the Standard Model, it is probably a good thing. But you should not confuse the frustration of others' choices with "insanity of mind" or a large conspiracy which would be controling the world of scientific research, I don't think this will be of any help in your life.

Comment: @Matt If you were replying to me, I was not notified, because you didn't properly addressed your comment with the @ sign - again :) The corruption is vast, but it hides behind the official propaganda, so most people are not aware.

Comment: @safesphere yes, sorry I had forgotten the @